# How can I use Portal in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about portals and where to place them. I understand that it basically has such structure

```
 <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="portal"></div>
  </body>
```

But can I create root div modal not in index.html, but somewhere else. For example in another component to let my portalComponent get exactly in certain part of my code, but not in index.html.

```
// for example
const Main = () => (
  <div className="grid-content">
    <Content />
{/* here I want to put my portalComponent */}
 <div id="portal"></div>
  </div>
);
```

Is it possible to do this way like in example above?

Comment: I guess you can do it , Just make sure the every component must have only one parent div and you portal should go inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a portal is essentially rendering an element adjacent to the root element to avoid nesting element(s) in the root DOM node.

Since react applications are SPA, placing the element outside of `index.html` would render it within the parent element(`root`), **although possible**, but contradicts the very meaning of portals.
The HTML of such an instance would look something like this:

```
<div id='root'>
   <div> <!-- Other components within root div, e.g: App -->
      <div id='portal'>{Portal component here}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, you can render the portal adjacent to the root element by creating the portal from anywhere(any component).

```
const Main = () => (
  <div className="grid-content">
    <Content />
    {ReactDOM.createPortal(<YourComponent/>,document.getElementById('portal')}
  </div>
);
```

If you happen to create an element within a component and wish to create a portal in that element, there are chances that you could see an error saying, `target container is not a DOM element`, which is quite obvious because of how react works. The elements of a component are added to the DOM only after the component is rendered, and trying to access an element that is still not added to the DOM gives the above error.
As a workaround, you could simply render the portal once the component is mounted. You could make use of the `useEffect` hook for this purpose.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useEffect,useState} from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <div id="portal"></div>
      {mounted && ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>Hello World, from portal</h1>, document.getElementById("portal"))}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got error: "Target container is not a DOM element"
Why did it happen?

Comment: That is because you're trying to access an element that is not present in the DOM. I've updated my answer, kindly check.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. But I have the same error. I tried to figure out why it happens. At the first render probably portal is created faster than my component where I want to mount smth.  Thats why it does not have access to document.getElementById("portal")
I tried to check 

{!!document.getElementById("portal")) && createPortal(<h1>Hello World, from portal</h1>, document.getElementById("portal"))}
But this approach is bad, because at the first render this portal does not appear, only at the second render it appears. Thats why I am a little puzzled what to do.

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox of this and share the link? It'll help me assess the issue and better address your problem.